# WP_Query sort using multiple numeric meta values

Tags: php, wp-query

I'm trying to sort custom posts using multiple numeric meta values but I only has success when sorting with just a single meta key.

In resume, I've two numeric meta keys `pwa_score` and `installs`. I need to order the results fisrt by `pwa_score` and second by `installs`, both in descending order.

The code bellow works like a charm for sorting by `pwa_score` only.

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'apps',
  'post_status' => 'public',
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
  'paged' => $page,
  'suppress_filters' => true,
  'category_name' => $slug,
  'meta_key' => 'pwa_score',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In case of trying to sort by multiple numeric meta keys using the sample bellow the results are aways incorrect. Its orders by `pwa_score` first, but `installs` appears to be random.

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'apps',
  'post_status' => 'public',
  'posts_per_page' => 1000,
  'suppress_filters' => true,
  'category_name' => $slug,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'pwa_score_clause' => array( 'key' => 'pwa_score', 'type' => 'numeric' ),
    'installs_clause' => array( 'key' => 'installs', 'type' => 'numeric' ),
  ),
  'orderby' => array(
    'pwa_score_clause' => 'DESC',
    'installs_clause' => 'DESC',
  ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How can I proper achieve this orderby using multiple numeric keys?

Comment: Welcome to the community :)
Your `orderby` parameter value isn't valid. Check the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).  
And I think unfortunately it's not possible to specify different orders for multi meta orderby values using the class.

Comment: In the `meta_query` arrays, try adding a "compare" like `'compare' => 'EXISTS'`. That might give you the results sorted in the order you preferred.

Comment: @Yashar, that `orderby` values are valid. See the parameter's description [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) which says "To sort by a specific `$meta_query` clause, use that clause's array key." :)

Comment: @SallyCJ you're right. just read the source of the class.